# In Ruby, can you store a point to a node in a hash for later replacement

Tags: ruby, pointers, hash

I have to assemble some massive JSON payloads, and I want to avoid massive duplicately nested leaves.  What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
tree = {}
tree[0] = {}
tree[0][1] = "stub"

# now save this pointer for later
stub = &tree[0][1]

...

# now go get the leaf

leaf = {0 => ["a","b","c"}

# now without having to search the entire tree, just use the old stub pointer

stub = leaf
```

Can this be done in Ruby?

Thanks for any help,
kevin

Comment: I don't understand your question, but it kinda sounds like you're looking for [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig)?

Comment: @max I think he might want leaves to appear in multiple places in tree without duplicating the leaves, so more of a reference sharing issue than a leaf finding issue.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have pointers (at least not at the Ruby level) but we do have references. So you could use a real hash instead of your `"stub"` string:

```
tree = {}
tree[0] = {}
tree[0][1] = {}
```

then stash that reference in `leaf`:

```
leaf = tree[0][1]
```

and modify the content of `leaf` without assigning anything new to `leaf`:

```
leaf[0] = %w[a b c]
```

That would leave you with `tree[0][1]` being `{0 => ['a', 'b', 'c']}` as desired. Of course, if you say `leaf = {0 => %w[a b c]}` then you'll have a new reference and you'll break the connection with `tree[0][1]`.

Usually this goes in the other direction. When you need a new leaf, you create it:

```
leaf = {0 => %w[a b c]}
```

and then you put that leaf in the tree:

```
tree[0][1] = leaf
tree[0][6] = leaf # Possibly in multiple places
```

Then you could say `leaf[11] = %w[x y z]` and `tree[0][1][11]` and `tree[0][6][11]` would also be `['x', 'y', 'z']` because `leaf`, `tree[0][1]`, and `tree[0][6]` would all refer to the same underlying hash.